# in-place modification of strings within a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to change some elements of a list based on the properties of previous ones.  Because I need to assign an intermediate variable, I don't think this can be done as a list comprehension.  The following code, with comment, is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
for H in header:
    if "lower" in H.lower():
        pref="lower"
    elif "higher" in H.lower():
        pref="higher"
    if header.count(H) > 1:
        # change H inplace
        H = pref+H
```

The best solution I've come up with is:

```
for ii,H in enumerate(header):
    if "lower" in H.lower():
        pref="lower"
    elif "higher" in H.lower():
        pref="higher"
    if header.count(H) > 1:
        header[ii] = pref+H
```

It doesn't quite work, and feels un-pythonic to me because of the indexing.  Is there a better way to do this?

Concrete example:

```
header = ['LowerLevel','Term','J','UpperLevel','Term','J']
```

desired output:

```
header = ['LowerLevel','LowerTerm','LowerJ','UpperLevel','UpperTerm','UpperJ']
```

Note that neither of my solutions work: the former never modifies `header` at all, the latter only returns
`header = ['LowerLevel','LowerTerm','LowerJ','UpperLevel','Term','J']`
because `count` is wrong after the modifications.

Comment: What's wrong with the first version?

Comment: Doesn't work.  The elements of `header` are never changed; `H` is overwritten each time.  Actually, the 2nd way doesn't work either.

Comment: The second version is often the best way to modify a list in-place. This is one of the main uses for `enumerate`. It's perfectly pythonic.

Comment: Strings are immutable so you simply cannot change them in-place. You'll always have to reassign the elements to the list or create a new list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header   = ['LowerLevel','Term','J','UpperLevel','Term','J']
prefixes = ['lower', 'upper']

def prefixed(header):
    prefix = ''

    for h in header:
        for p in prefixes:
            if h.lower().startswith(p):
                prefix, h = h[:len(p)], h[len(p):]
        yield prefix + h

print list(prefixed(header))
```

I don't really know that this is better than what you had. It's *different*...

```
$ ./lower.py
['LowerLevel', 'LowerTerm', 'LowerJ', 'UpperLevel', 'UpperTerm', 'UpperJ']
```

Comment: +1 for the attempt; I like the approach.  However, it doesn't work on the concrete example I just added (made it because I saw your short-lived previous version).  The problem with this - which I didn't make perfectly clear - is that it only considers 1 previous element, but I need to look back 2 for this case.

Comment: @keflavich I see, thanks for the update w/sample data. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 2):

something like this, using generator function:

```
In [62]: def func(lis):
    pref=""
    for x in lis:
        if "lower" in x.lower():
            pref="Lower"
        elif "upper" in x.lower():    
            pref="Upper"
        if header.count(x)>1:    
            yield pref+x
        else:      
            yield x
   ....:             

In [63]: list(func(header))
Out[63]: ['LowerLevel', 'LowerTerm', 'LowerJ', 'UpperLevel', 'UpperTerm', 'UpperJ']
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for the data you presented.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_dups(seq):
    '''Finds duplicates in a sequence and returns a dict
            of value:occurences'''
    seen = defaultdict(int)
    for curr in seq:
        seen[curr] += 1
    d = dict([(i, seen[i]) for i in seen if seen[i] > 1])
    return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    header = ['LowerLevel','Term','J','UpperLevel','Term','J']
    d = find_dups(header)
    for i, s in enumerate(header):
        if s in d:
            if d[s] % 2:
                pref = 'Upper'
            else:
                pref = 'Lower'
            header[i] = pref + s
            d[s] -= 1
```

But it give me the creeps to suggest anything, not knowing but a little about the entire set of data you will be working with.

good luck,

Mike